# Can't get command line addition of users to work Windows 2008 server

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008

I have a task to set up a Windows 2008 server in AWS, fully scripted.

I need to add a user but so far have tried *dsadd* with no apparent results. I tried various permutations of the command and finally copied and pasted the example:

```
dsadd user “cn=John Smith,ou=SouthEmployees,dc=northwindtraders,dc=com” -disabled no –pwd C^h3Bdo9# -mustchpwd yes
```

But nothing extra shows up in the server manager list of local users, and the command just returns with no indication of error or success.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong, or another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This had to be done with PowerShell:

```
# Add required ID

$server=[ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername"
$user=$server.Create('User','my_username')
$user.SetPassword('longpassword')
$user.SetInfo()
```